# How do a request get with axios passing params?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I want to send params from react to expressjs, i am using axios method get

```
const searchQuery = 'any' 
let users = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/v1/users/search', {params:{data:searchQuery}})
```

and in my backend

```
router.get('/search/:query', UserController.searchUsers);


static async searchUsers(req, res) {
    const { searchQuery } = req.params
    console.log('searchQuery',req.params, searchQuery)
```

i am getting this:

```
/v1/users/search?data=ddas
```

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let users = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/v1/users/search', {params:{data:searchQuery}})
```

your **query parameter** is `data`.
To access it in your backend

```js
const { data } = req.query;
```